# SQL get highest rate of change in time series

Tags: sql, sqlite, time-series

I have a table that contains the timestamp and temperature.  I want to get the highest rate of change of the temperature each day.  Is there a formula, or aggregate function that does that?

I can get the highest rate via a program that gets each row in sequential order and determine the change between the two rows, but wondering if there is a function ready for that.

Answer (score 0):

SQL has the `LAG` function which can be used to get the value from a previous row.

Using something like the below SQL statement, I can get the previous temperature and the time since the last reading:

```
SELECT datetime, temp,
   (LAG(temp, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) - Temp) PrevTemp,
   (julianday(datetime) - LAG(julianday(datetime), 1, 0) OVER (order by datetime))*24*60 TimeDIff
   FROM temperature 
  ORDER BY datetime
```

The results are something like this:

```
'2022-08-11 22:44:40', 33.000, -0.06300000000000239, 12.316666916012764
'2022-08-11 22:45:11', 32.937,  0.06300000000000239,  0.5166665464639664
'2022-08-11 22:47:15', 33.000, -0.06300000000000239,  2.066666856408119
'2022-08-11 22:48:16', 32.937,  0.06300000000000239,  1.016666516661644
'2022-08-11 22:49:18', 33.000, -0.06300000000000239,  1.0333330929279327
```